# How to access group members on LInkedIn

Tags: javascript, linkedin-api

Is it possible, as a group administrator, to list all the members from a group so other users can see who they are and connect with them?

I want to do this from the API and integrate LinkedIn with my website.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to respect the privacy of group members, it's not possible to export a list of group members. This simply violates the policy of LinkedIn.

Answer (score 0):

Hi @deccks you can use [group memberships for a user API](https://developer-programs.linkedin.com/documents/groups-api#membergroups) from Linkedin